# How to add toolbar in a single view in RAP?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I have a View class extend ViewPart and I want to add a toolbar in that view. I think the best way is use Action.
But I'm a beginner for eclipse RAP and don't know how to make it. Need help.

I also tried this code below but it doesn't work.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    IWorkbenchWindow iWorkbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    openViewAction = new OpenViewAction(iWorkbenchWindow, "Open Another Message View", View.ID);

    ICoolBarManager coolBar = new CoolBarManager();

    IToolBarManager toolbar1 = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);  
        coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(toolbar1, "label"));  
        toolbar1.add(openViewAction);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way by use extensions. This is what I did

> plugin.xml > Extensions > org.eclipse.ui.menus > right-click > New > menuContribution > locationURI = toolbar:view_id > right-click > New > command > commandId > Browse

You guy can find more in [this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_RCP_How-to#View_Toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below line of code to your **View->createPartControl()** method:

```
getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager().add(openViewAction);
```